# In a Unity Camera Stack: how to grab a Camera's "view texture" (to be used inside of a shader)?

Tags: unity, shaders, post-processing, rendertexture

Here is the situation:

- I have a URP Camera Stack; actually just two cameras: a perspective base & an orthogonal overlay.
- I have some distortion shader (example, not mine) that "runs" only on
  materials that the 2nd camera sees. This is just a side task of the
  2nd camera: it's mostly for... overlay stuff that's related on top of
  the 2.5 game (it's not just UI either).
- These distortion shaders cannot not use _CameraOpaqueTexture because it, at least in my
  project, doesn't capture transparent nor post    processing effects.
  (And thus, I cannot use Shader Graph's SceneColor    Node either - as that is what it uses).
- Fortunately, URP has another "sorta-hidden/undocumented"    GlobalTexture called
  _AfterPostProcessing that is exactly what I    need. Hooray!
- Unfortunately, it has come to my attention that this only works ifthe game has anti-aliasing! That's ultimately what the universal pipeline is using it for, and I just happen to be able to use it for my needs.

I figured I need to create a GlobalTexture myself, and I figured perhaps the way to do this is in a ScriptableRendererFeature. Here is the core of my (bad?) attempt to achieve this.

public class GetFirstCameraViewPass : ScriptableRenderPass

```
{ ...
 
public override void Execute(ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData renderingData) { Camera currentCamera = renderingData.cameraData.camera;
 
   RenderTexture renderTexture = new RenderTexture(3840, 2160, 0);
   currentCamera.targetTexture = renderTexture;
   currentCamera.Render();
   currentCamera.targetTexture = null;
 
   CommandBuffer cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get();
   cmd.SetGlobalTexture(GlobalTexturePropertyName, renderTexture);
   context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
   CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
 
}
 
  ...
 
}
```

But I get this error when I do that:

> Recursive rendering is not supported in SRP (are you calling
> Camera.Render from within a render pipeline?).
>
> UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()

How do I achieve this in a custom pass/feature?

Or is it possible to have _CameraOpaqueTexture capture transparent textures, in the settings somehow? It nearly does what I need it do in the scene view:

[image: At least in the Scene view (Left) the Shader captures post processing! (Unlike in-gameplay: Right side)]
This is an example scene of my trying to figure out a solution. At least in the Scene view (Left) the Shader captures post processing! (Unlike in-gameplay: Right side)

Or is there another, smarter & completely different way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?